# Undefined return value. How to use a callback in this case?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I'm sorry, I know this has been asked a thousand times, but I've read the responses and I still don't get it. I'm new to Javascript (I started yesterday, actually) and I have the following problem:

I have an asynchronous function, and I need the returned value, but it is undefined, of course. I've read about callbacks, but I'm not sure how they work.

The function is the following:

```
function getLatLong(address){
      var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder;

      geo.geocode({'address':address},function(results, status){
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                var returnedLatLng = [];
                returnedLatLng["lat"] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                returnedLatLng["lgn"] = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                locationTarget = new google.maps.LatLng(returnedLatLng.lat,returnedLatLng.lgn);
                alert(locationTarget);
                return locationTarget;
              } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
              }

       });
  }
```

I'm calling this function from an initialize() function and I'm doing it this way:

```
var location = getLatLong(address);
```

Well, my question is how would a callback help me out here? and if it's possible.. what code should I use?

Thanks a lot! (This is my first very first question here!)

Answer (score 0):

The most basic solution to start with will be to define your location globally and to respond to the callback you already have:

```
var location;
function getLatLong(address){
      var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder;

      geo.geocode({'address':address},function(results, status){
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                var returnedLatLng = [];
                returnedLatLng["lat"] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                returnedLatLng["lgn"] = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                locationTarget = new google.maps.LatLng(returnedLatLng.lat,returnedLatLng.lgn);
                alert(locationTarget);
                location = locationTarget;
                // Additional logic you are using the location for
                // After this point your location is defined.
              } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
              }

       });
  }
 getLatLong(address)
```

So basically your logic needs to be based not on a call to this method that returns location but rather on something that happens after the `geocode` function callback is called.

Comment: Thank you for such I quick answer. I had tried to do something like that. I totally forgot to mention that. Anyway, it didn't work. Once I'm out of the function, the global variable is undefined again.

You said " and to respond to the callback you already have:" I'm sorry but, do I already have a callback? I just don't seem to understand the concept

Comment: @gpanich The function that is defined as a parameter to the geocode function is a callback function. The global variable will be undefined until that callback is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var locationCallback = function(location){
        // your fancy code here
    };
function getLatLong(address){
      var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder;

      geo.geocode({'address':address},function(results, status){
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                var returnedLatLng = [];
                returnedLatLng["lat"] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                returnedLatLng["lgn"] = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                locationTarget = new google.maps.LatLng(returnedLatLng.lat,returnedLatLng.lgn);
                alert(locationTarget);

                //this is your callback
                locationCallback(locationTarget);


              } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
              }

       });
  }
 getLatLong(address)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I have so many questions, I feel so dumb right now, but I'm totally new to this.What do you mean by "your fancy code here"? What code are you talking about? Is the "return value" stored in locationCallback now? and finally.. Why is the function called there (getLatLong(address), I mean).

Comment: I assume that you want to do something with the content of locationTarget. So when the callback function is called you can be sure that your locationTarget is there and you can process the result.